# For who you are OR as you are?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I'd like to construct this sentence, which one is a better way to put it?

I like you for who you are
OR
I like you as you are

What is the difference between for what something is vs as something is?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They'd normally be understood as meaning two slightly different things...

> *I like you for who you are*

I like you because I like your inner qualities as a person, rather than because of "superficial" attributes (beauty, wealth, status, etc.)

> *I like you as you are*

I don't want you to change - exactly how you are now is how I like you being

Comment: for sth is : stress on the "inner essence" as it is: stress on being same? If I change the example how would the meaning change? Can we derive a general rule out of these examples?    "I want you to accept it for what it is VS I want you to accept it as it is"

Comment: They're not particularly good examples from which to derive a more general "rule" for possible differences between ***for*** and ***as***. Better might be *The policeman came to my party **as a guest*** (***how*** he came) and ***...for a guest*** (***why*** he came, perhaps to arrest one of my guests). I think that *how / why* distinction is essentially the same as your example. ***Why** do I like you? Because of / **for** your personality / **who** you are. **How** do I like you? The way / how / **as** you are (currently).*

Comment: nirvana had a lyrics "come as you are", how would the meaning change if he instead said: come for who you are?

Comment: @CeyhunÖzsoylu: *Come **as** you are* is in common use (it means *You don't need to make a special effort to get dressed up / put on make-up / etc.*). I've never heard anyone say *Come **for who** you are*, but I can imagine *I only invited you for who you are* (I didn't invite you because you because you're a *friend* - you're only at my party because of your social status or similar).